# if center of Group is of index n,prove that every conjugacy class has almost n elements

Tags: group-theory

Let G be finite group,z(G) denotes center of Group of index n,then number of elements in every conjugacy class are almost n.

Comment: Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, please post what you know and have done or so far. It helps as a starting point.

Comment: Hint: Consider $|C_{G}(x)|$ for $x \in G.$

Comment: You wrote "almost" by  most probably meant to write "at most".

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at the conjugacy class that contains element $a$.

We can write it as $\{gag^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$.

Realize that $G$ is the union of all left cosets of $Z(G)$.

If $gZ(G)=hZ(G)$ or equivalently $g=hz$ for some $z\in Z(G)$ then: $$gag^{-1}=hzaz^{-1}h^{-1}=hazz^{-1}h^{-1}=hah^{-1}$$

So all elements that belong to the same coset of $Z(G)$ will induce the same element of the conjugacy class of $a$.

There are $n$ cosets of $Z(G)$, so...

Actually the demand that $G$ is finite can be dropped.

Comment: Finiteness of $G$ is a consequence of the conjugacy classes being at most $n$, because they partition $G$. Is that right?

Comment: @user193319 Not if the number of conjugacy classes is not finite.

Comment: So if two elements $g, h$ are in the same coset of the center, then they are both conjugate to $a$. But why can't the coset have size bigger than $n$, in which case the conjugacy class of $a$ would have size bigger than $n$?

Comment: @Junglemath I am not saying that elements $g,h$ in the same coset of the center are both conjugate to $a$. What I am saying is actually that the map $\{\text{cosets of center}\}\to\text{conjugacy class of }a$ prescribed by $gZ(G)\to gag^{-1}$ is *well defined*. Also the map is surjective and consequently the conjugacy class of $a$ cannot have more elements than the number of elements of $\{\text{cosets of center}\}$.

Comment: I see. If $b$ is in the conjugacy class of $a$, which element of $G/Z(G)$ maps to $b$?

Comment: @Junglemath $gZ(G)$ maps to $b$ iff $gag^{-1}=b$. There is at least one $g$ such that the equality is satisfied because $b$ is an element of the conjugacy class of $a$. It is quite well possible that more than one element maps to $b$. The function is not necessarily injective.